# Inserting element into sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays

What I need to do is work from the back of an array (I must use a dynamic array). When filling the array, I need to check that if the element I wish to insert is less than the current element, I must shift those elements to create a 'hole'.

Say I have an array that looks like so:

```
index:    0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4
value:    10  |   11  |   13  |   14  |   NULL
```

In my current code, the array size is always 1 larger than the current size. So in the above, the size of the array would be 5. This allows for shifting around.

Now lets say I need to insert the element `12` into the array. So I need to begin with position `4` or `x[3]` which has a value of `14`.

I've currently got the following:

```
// theSize is a private member of a class that holds the array
int j = theSize - 1;
// dynamic allocation
int *temp = new int[theSize];
for (int k = 0; k < theSize; k++) {
    temp[k] = x[k];
}
delete [] x;
// using j >=0 because I need to check as low as the x[0] value
for(; j >=0 && element < temp[j]; --j) {
    // So in the first run starting at x[3]
    //    this would be the value at x[3] is now at x[4]
    temp[j] = temp[j+1];
}

temp[j] = element;
x = temp;
delete [] temp;
theSize++
```

So for example, after this runs the first time, the array would look like:

```
index:    0   |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4
value:    10  |   11  |   13  |       |   14
```

I see a lot of examples of shifting through an array from the back but changing:

`x[j] = x[j+1]` to `x[j] = x[j-1]`

I'm not sure why you would want `x[j-1]` as that is 1 value the left and I want to shift to the right.

Does my understanding of array indexing need correction?

**TL:DR**
The problem I am having is that sometimes, when comparing `element < temp[j]` the Boolean is returning that the value is not less than, when it is in fact. I've gone through a debugger already, and the right values are being compared, but it leaves me wondering if it is pulling a value from an old array index.

Comment: have a look at `memcpy`.

Comment: Have a look at std::vector. It has a insert method.

Comment: @manni66 First line of the post. I must use a dynamic array. No vectors.

Comment: @pasta_sauce `std::vector` is *the* standard runtime-sized array in C++, not any kind of `new[]` business.

Comment: Technical point: arrays in C++ are not *dynamic*, as in they do not change after allocation. Arrays can be *dynamically allocated*. `std::vector` is *dynamic*.

Comment: @BaummitAugen "I have to use X" is usually a strong indication that this is a homework thing. Otherwise people tend to use whatever makes sense.

Comment: @BaummitAugen As much as I would love to use a `std::vector` I cannot. Must use the method of `int *temp = new int[theSize]`

Comment: @crashmstr Fair point. I need to dynamically allocate within the array, and I cant quite figure out why I am unable to work down through the array.

Comment: @Borgleader Indeed. Its not homework, nor is it school work, it is a particular assignment given to me, and the requester specifically asked for the use of `new[ ]`

Comment: @pasta_sauce we all believe this. Use a debugger. Step through your code and look what it is doing.

Comment: "I need to insert the element 12 into the array. So I need to begin with position 4 or x[3] which has a value of 14." This doesn't make sense. Why do you insert 12 between 13 and 14?

Comment: Your customer may be stupid. Anyway, putting unjustified and arbitrary requirements to your question may make your question irrelevant altogether.

Comment: @DanielDaranas It is saying I have to begin with `14` or `x[3]`. I only show a single go through in the loop. Obviously it doesn't get put into the position between `13` or `14`. The loop would continue again and move `13` to the right one and then the hole would be at `x[2]`.

Comment: Is there an actual problem here? Does the code not work?

Comment: @DanielDaranas What the customer requests in not arbitrary and that's not for you to decide. The question is simple: Is the method correct for starting at last index of array, comparing size, if not, moving that index right one step, check next index, repeat until insertion point found.

Comment: It _is_ arbitrary. Requesting not to use a standard C++ container _is_ arbitrary. There's no way you can make it not arbitrary.

Comment: @pasta_sauce You're just doing the inner loop of Insertion Sort. Go look at the example pseudo-code on Wikipedia.

Comment: @DanielDaranas You and I do not know what other constraints their remaining code has and/or why a `std::array` is required over a `std::vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your code is buggy (you have one `new[]` but two `delete[]`, how do you think that can work?)

```
int *temp = new int[theSize];
/* ... */
x = temp;
delete [] temp;       // delete memory pointed to by x
```

you just delete the dynamically allocated array, rendering `x` a dangling pointer. I'm surprised you didn't get a segmentation fault. Just remove the `delete[] temp;`

---

Also, there is no need to first copy all data to a temporary array and then shuffle. You can do all in just one sweep:

```
int k = Size;             // Size is the actual size, not one larger
int*temp = new int[Size+1];
for(; k && element < x[k-1]; --k)
  temp[k] = x[k-1];
temp[k] = element;
for(; k; --k)
  temp[k-1] = x[k-1];
delete[] x;
x = temp;
++Size;
```

Comment: So I have `delete [] x` earlier in the code. Move it down? And do I not need to `delete [] temp`?

Comment: @pasta_sauce I missed that. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Two things: 1. Why `k && ...` and not `k > 0 && ...` or `k >=0 && ...`? 2. The second `for`, is that to get all the values in the front that weren't touched?

Comment: @pasta_sauce If you go through these loops line by line, you'll see why. (hint inside the loop it refers to `x[k-1]`). The first loop copies all entries larger than `element` but one index up. The second loop copies all entries smaller than `element` to the same index. The method to use `k` as loop variable and `k-1` as index is actually the same that `reverse_iterator` uses, it allows unsigned data types.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) and [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) as it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::set<int> x={10,11,13,14};
    x.insert(12);


    for (const int& i : x) // access by const reference
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example!](http://ideone.com/Asktwu)

Result:

> 10 11 12 13 14

**Note:**
This make your data stored in `x` to be sorted and unique, if you want you can change it to `std::multiset`(Unlike set, multiple keys with equivalent values are allowed).

Comment: What does this solve? I have no problem inserting values into the array.

Comment: @pasta_sauce `std::set` keep your data unique and sorted

Comment: You should mention the assumption you made - namely that there is no need to store duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, your code produces memory leaks and undefined behaviour as you assign `x = temp` after having freed `temp`.

Second, I'd separate the code for finding an element from the code that shifts the elements in the array instead of copying one value after the other on your own. For copying elements, you can use `std::copy_n` and `std::copy_backward` (if source and target range overlap). For finding the "nearest" value, you can use `std::lower_bound`. See the following code that adapts your program to the use of those functions:

```
int main() {

    int *x = new int[4] { 10  ,   11  ,   13  ,   14 };
    int theSize = 4;

    int *temp = new int[theSize+1];
    std:copy_n(x, theSize, temp);
    int* f = std::lower_bound(temp,temp+theSize,12);
    std::copy_backward(f,temp+theSize,temp+theSize+1);
    *f = 12;
    delete[] x;
    x = temp;
    theSize++;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Not enough rep to comment, finally made an account after a long time lurker.  I would look into using a doubly linked list, makes iteration through lists and injecting variables at set locations much easier.  For example you can reference the first and last items using, header.back which would be the last item think of it as a circle, and header.next which would reference the first item depending how you define header.  You can manipulate linked lists as much as you need for your own use case being that each item references the one before and after it.  If that sounds beneficial I can dig some projects for a solid example.